# Websphere MQ add Exception Listener

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am using IBM Websphere MQ 7.0.1 and I am trying to apply it a JMS exception listener.

On normal JMS I would do something like this:

```
connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListenerImpl());
```

I can't find out how to do it.

Can anyone provide an example (I am using JAVA)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get exception listener callbacks, you need to create a JMS session against the connection which you're registering your exception on. This should work:

```
Connection conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session = createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
conn.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListenerImpl());
```

Comment: and how do I get the connection factory from the Webshphere MQ?